# Solr 7 - How to do Full Text Search w/ Geo Spatial Search

Tags: solr, lucene

## How to do Full Text combined w/ Geo Spatial in Solr 7?

In regards to this: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/spatial-search.html

I have to do queries that **COMBINE** full text w/ geo spatial. For example:

`box AND full text` or `spatial sort AND full text`.

I was not able to figure out a good query string example that produces this desired result. I would like this as a pure query string rather than some Java method as I'm consuming this on different tech other than Java. Solr is very deep and confusing and I know I must read more but there was no good examples for this anywhere online that I found.

**desired query string example**

```
[solr]/select?fq={!bbox sfield=point}&pt=34.04506799999999,-118.260849&d=10000&sort=geodist() asc&{!geofilt}&sfield=point&q=Panini
```

So in that case, would sort by distance yet also filter by some full text "some text" value.

If this cannot be done, I believe it is possible in Elastic Search but these (Solr and Elastic Search) are both built on top of Lucene so seems like it should work on both if works on one but feel free to supply an answer for Elastic Search as well.

**example returned**

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 2,
    "params": {
        "q": "Panini",
        "pt": "34.04506799999999,-118.260849",
        "d": "10000",
        "{!geofilt}": "",
        "fq": "{!bbox sfield=point}",
        "sort": "geodist() asc",
        "sfield": "point"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
  }
}
```

Docs do contain this phrase 'Panini' but none returned. May be due to default way full text is handled in Solr 7? It is using the same point where the term 'Panini' is used and the field point is of type org.apache.solr.schema.PointType.

**UPDATE**

I ended up abandoning Solr for Elastic Search. Solr is just very annoying in its strange ways compared with the very easy to use Elastic Search. Things just work as you expect without having to dig into quirks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adapted my answer to the solr 7.2.1 example:

Start solr by: `./bin/solr start -e techproducts`

I've also visualized the data in google maps:
https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?ll=42.00542239270033%2C-89.81213734375001&hl=en&hl=en&z=4&mid=16gaLvuWdE9TsnhcbK-BMu5DVYMzR9Vir

You need these [query parameters](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/spatial-search.html#searching-with-query-parsers):

**Bound by Box Filter:**

- fq={!bbox}

**The geo filter query parser bbox needs further parameters:**

- Solr field: sfield=store
- Point to search/sort from: pt=36.35,-97.51
- Distance for filter: d=1200

**Sort:**

- sort=geodist() asc

**Fulltext query:**

- q=some+text

**Full example queries for solr example data:**

**Simple:**
[http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select?fq={!bbox}&sort=geodist()%20asc&sfield=store&pt=36.35,-97.51&d=1200&q=ipod&fl=name,store](http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select?fq=%7B!bbox%7D&sort=geodist()%20asc&sfield=store&pt=36.35,-97.51&d=1200&q=ipod&fl=name,store)

**UI:**
[http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/browse?fq={!bbox}&sort=geodist()%20asc&sfield=store&pt=36.35,-97.51&d=1200&q=ipod](http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/browse?fq=%7B!bbox%7D&sort=geodist()%20asc&sfield=store&pt=36.35,-97.51&d=1200&q=ipod)

The result is as expected:

1. Apple 60 GB iPod
2. Belkin Power Cord for iPod
3. Filtered by distance: iPod & iPod Mini USB 2.0 Cable

**Hints**

- The field store must be of type location:
- You might [Urlencode](https://www.urlencoder.org/) the special characters: 
  e.g. fq=%7B%21bbox%20sfield%3DgeoLocation%7D

Comment: It should be possible in a single query. I've put the whole query in my answer. Please let me know, if it doesn't work. Perhaps there's a syntax error. I've checked the query on my local system with some other data.

Comment: I adapted my answer to the solr 7.2.1 example data, so that you can reproduce it. I also simplified the query. You just need bbox or geofilt.

Comment: still having 0 results: You must ensure, that your fulltext query queries on the right fields. I prefer the edismax parser. Here you can specify the fields by the qf param. e.g. qf=name,text Confusing?

Comment: Turns out the main issue was not having a default way to search without specifying key in q param i.e. q=field:abc but not q=abc  thanks!

Comment: Although quite late: There is in fact a way to search in a default field: `df:field` would it be for you. :) You can give it in both every single query or your `solrconfig.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you have to combine the full-text search scoring with the spatial distance.

So if your query looks like this:

```
/select?fq={!bbox sfield=point}&pt=34.04506799999999,-118.260849&d=10000&sort=geodist() asc&{!geofilt}&sfield=point&q=Panini
```

You should change the `sort` parameter and either remove it or just set it to `score desc`. That way you sort by the score given from the full-text search query.

To take the spatial part into consideration you need to include a boosting function to your query. In majority of the cases - the closer the document is from the point of interest the better, so you would probably like to include a boosting function that does `X/distance`. The `X` can be as simple as `1` and the function itself can also be more complicated. To do that in `dismax` query you would use the `bf` parameter, like `bf=div(1,geodist())`.

Try that out, it should work, but of course will need some adjustments.

Comment: in hindsite, I didn't need to go to ElasticSearch but I ended up doing that. They are essentially wrappers for Lucene but Elastic seems a little easier at times.